# Latex List of figures error in texfull live 2019

Tags: latex, pdflatex

Hi guys i have a issue with compiling list of figures in latex

for some figures after figure this thing keeps coming

3.1 NAS3A Rotor-37 Coarse Mesh and Coarse solution aligned with flow field, with 590k node count 15
16subfigure.2.1
16subfigure.2.2
16subfigure.2.1
16subfigure.2.2

those subfigures are unknown idk where are they coming from anyone can help

i am trying it on latex 2019 texstudio please help thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.